# Android permissions GET_ACCOUNTS and USE_CREDENTIALS show up automatically

Tags: android, android-permissions

It has been quite a few months since I had time to work on my app. And today I downloaded latest Android Studio and SDK, I found a problem after I built the app.

My AndroidManifest file does NOT require any permissions on GET_ACCOUNTS or USE_CREDENTIALS, however they are shown as new added permissions when I tried to upload the app in Google Play store. I did use Google Play Games service in the game, but it was not like this before I did this update.

Does anybody know why? I Googled a while but could not find any clue..

Comment: I think it is related to this https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html#overview

Comment: Include your `build.gradle`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you recently updated, check to see if you switched to Google Play services 7.5 with a line in your `build.gradle` file such as

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

Google Play services 7.5 automatically adds required permissions - when you use `com.google.android.gms:play-services` - that says you are using *every* part of Google Play services, potentially adding more permissions than you intended.

Instead, you should [selectively include what APIs you use](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split) by using separate dependencies such as:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:7.5.0'
```

(Assuming you'd need Drive for [Saved Games support](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames))