# ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION merged from play-services-base lib

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-manifest, android-permissions

I'm using Android Studio to build my project, and after looking at the `manifest-merger-debug-report.txt` file, I see the following permission was added to my manifest:

```
ADDED from com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.5.0:22:13
uses-permission#android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
```

It seems as if play-services lib merged the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission to my manifest. I am using the play services in order to support GCM in my library (play-services-gcm). I've been using the play-services lib for a long time, until the recent update of the lib, which seemed to add this permission for some reason. This is obviously not wanted on my end, as less users will trust my app.

Is there anyway I can still use the lib, without this unnecessary permission?

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699993/android-permissions-get-accounts-and-use-credentials-show-up-automatically

Comment: Same thing here, and we're getting a few support requests about this new permission. People are particularly sensitive to location permissions.

Answer (score 7):

Google Play services 7.5 automatically adds required permissions - when you use `com.google.android.gms:play-services` - that says you are using every part of Google Play services, potentially adding more permissions than you intended.

You may need to selectively compile just the Google Play Service APIs you need.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split) is a link to the separated libs, and here is the list as it was at time of writing:

---

**Google+** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0`

**Google Account Login** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.5.0`

**Google Actions, Base Client Library** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.5.0`

**Google App Indexing** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:7.5.0`

**Google App Invites** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:7.5.0`

**Google Analytics** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0`

**Google Cast** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:7.5.0`

**Google Cloud Messaging** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0`

**Google Drive** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:7.5.0`

**Google Fit** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:7.5.0`

**Google Location, Activity Recognition, and Places** `com.google.android.gms:play-
services-location:7.5.0`

**Google Maps** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0`

**Google Mobile Ads** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0`

**Google Nearby** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:7.5.0`

**Google Panorama Viewer** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:7.5.0`

**Google Play Game services** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:7.5.0`

**SafetyNet** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:7.5.0`

**Google Wallet** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:7.5.0`

**Android Wear** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.5.0`

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove" />
```

to your main manifest to remove this permission.